# How can i add previous results from a loop into a dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm trying to add the previous results of a loop into the dictionary. I want it to add new results after an iteration.
What I mean by this is a dictionary saves the results from every iteration. So it starts with one result and adds the next result of the iteration after that but not in the same dictionary.

An example, this is after the first looping over it.

```
{'head': 1, 'leg':1, 'arm':2}
```

Then in the next loop it sees the line

```
{'eye': 1, 'leg':1, 'arm':2}
```

and it creates

```
{'head': 1, 'leg':1, 'arm':2}
{'eye': 1, 'leg':1, 'arm':2}
```

I currently have the following code:

```
import nltk
import numpy
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwoorden = set(stopwords.words('english'))


with open("test1.txt") as t1, open("test2.txt") as t2:
    test1 = t1.read()
    test2 = t2.read()


for test in [test1,test2]:
    words = test.split()
    words = [word.lower()for word in words]
    stopwoorden_removed = [word for word in words if word not in stopwoorden]


    tf = {}
    for word in stopwoorden_removed:
        if word in tf:
            tf[word] = tf[word] + 1
        elif word not in tf:
            tf[word] = 1
        
print(tf)
```

I know append does not work with dictionaries. I wouldnt know how to implement the .update function in this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to understand what you are trying to achieve or what's wrong with your current code. Please edit the question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Add a little more information, it is unclear what is needed.

Comment: Move `tf = {}` outside of the outer loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare tf = {} before the for loop. Everything else looks fine.

Comment: This does seem to work yes! However I want it to create seperate dictionaries from it.
So after reading the first file, it creates a dictionary and after the second file it creates another one with the other results.
I forgot to specify this, my bad.

Comment: Have a list and append the tf dicts to it after you `for word in stopwoorden_removed:` is finished.